# Relation between jet and singularities of a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to understand the relationship between a jet and the singularities of a curve. Concretely I am trying to understand the following example:

Let $\gamma(t) = (\cos t , b \sin t)$ where $b > 0$ be an ellipse. Let $f$ be the distance squared function from $({1\over 2},0)$ to $\gamma (t)$ i.e.

$$ f(t) = ({1\over 2} - \cos t)^2 + b^2 \sin^2 t$$

For each $t_0$ consider the $2$-jet at $t_0$ of $f$:

$$ (\sin t_0 + (b^2 -1)\sin 2 t_0)t + (\cos t_0 + 2(b^2 -1)\cos 2 t_0) t^2$$

Writing this as $c_1 t + c_2 t^2$ the points $(c_1, c_2)$ will trace out a curve $\delta$ as $t_0$ varies. This curve will cross the $c_2-$axis at points where $f$ has a singularity $A_{\ge 1}$ at $t_0$ and will pass through the origin where $f$ has an $A_{\ge2}$ singularity at $t_0$. The geometrical interpretation of this is that $f$ has an $A_{\ge1}$ singularity at $t_0$ iff the normal to the ellipse at $\gamma (t_0)$ passes through $({1\over 2},0)$ and an $A_{\ge 2}$ singularity iff $({1\over 2},0)$ is the centre of curvature at $\gamma (t_0)$.

> I have absolutely no intuition about why the coefficients of the jet
>   should have the property that they trace out a curve and this curves
>   contains information about the singularities of the original curve.
>   Please could someone help me understand why this is true?

This example can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=rhq3YCguBOUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 57.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\gamma$ be a regular plane curve, $p_{0}$ a point of the plane, and
$$
f(t) = \|\gamma(t) - p_{0}\|^{2}
  = \bigl(\gamma(t) - p_{0}\bigr) \cdot \bigl(\gamma(t) - p_{0}\bigr).
$$
Note that
$$
f'(t) = 2\bigl(\gamma(t) - p_{0}\bigr) \cdot \gamma'(t),
\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
f''(t) = 2\bigl[\bigl(\gamma(t) - p_{0}\bigr) \cdot \gamma''(t) + \gamma'(t) \cdot \gamma'(t)\bigr].
\tag{2}
$$

Let $T$ be the unit tangent field and $N$ the normal field, and write $\gamma' = vT$, $T' = \kappa N$.

By (1), $f$ has a critical point at $t_{0}$ if and only if $\gamma'(t_{0})$ is orthogonal to the displacement $\gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0}$, if and only if $\gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0}$ is a multiple of $N$; by (2), $f''(t_{0}) = 0$ in addition if and only if
$$
\bigl(\gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0}\bigr) \cdot \gamma''(t_{0}) + \gamma'(t_{0}) \cdot \gamma'(t_{0}) = 0.
$$

Since $\gamma''(t_{0}) \cdot N(t_{0}) = \kappa(t_{0}) v(t_{0})^{2}$, the preceding equation gives
$$
\left\lVert \gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0} \right\rVert \kappa(t_{0}) v(t_{0})^{2}
  = \bigl(\gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0}\bigr) \cdot \gamma''(t_{0})
  = -v(t_{0})^{2},
$$
or $\left\lVert \gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0} \right\rVert = -1/\kappa(t_{0})$. That is,
$$
\gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0}
  = \left\lVert \gamma(t_{0}) - p_{0} \right\rVert N(t_{0})
  = -\frac{1}{\kappa(t_{0})} N(t_{0}),\quad\text{or}\quad
p_{0} = \gamma(t_{0}) + \frac{1}{\kappa(t_{0})} N(t_{0}),
$$
which means $p_{0}$ is the center of curvature.

The connection with $2$-jets is immediate: the $2$-jet of $f$ at $t_{0}$ is
$$
f(t_{0}) + f'(t_{0})(t - t_{0}) + \tfrac{1}{2} f''(t_{0})(t - t_{0})^{2}
  = c_{0} + c_{1}(t - t_{0}) + c_{2} (t - t_{0})^{2}.
$$
The curve $\bigl(c_{1}(t_{0}), c_{2}(t_{0})\bigr) = \bigl(f'(t_{0}), \frac{1}{2}f''(t_{0})\bigr)$ crosses the $c_{2}$-axis if and only if $c_{1}(t_{0}) = 0$, if and only if $f$ has a critical point at $t_{0}$; the curve touches the origin if and only if both components are zero, if and only if $p_{0}$ is the center of curvature of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(t_{0})$.